# Use of '{}' as end iterator in std::vector constructor

Tags: c++, iterator, istream-iterator

A way for reading a file and put it as a byte array into a vector would be:

```
std::ifstream input(filePath, std::ios::binary);
std::vector<unsigned char> barray(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});
```

As far as I understand, the constructor used for `std::vector` in the above code snippet is

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Thus, the `{}` corresponds to `last`.

What is exactly `{}`? Is it acting like a null/empty iterator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Thus, the {} corresponds to last.
>   What is exactly {}? Is it acting like a null/empty iterator?

It's a default constructed object of type `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> barray(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});
```

is the same as

```
std::vector<unsigned char> barray{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{input},
                                  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};
```

Comment: vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); it is this one. When first is given, InputIt type becomes std::istreambuf_iterator<char> and {} creates empty instance of it .

Comment: But then, why `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}` acts as the end of the `ifstream`? Is it like telling to vector 'read until the iterator becomes '{}', which is an empty/null iterator, so it marks the end of something'?

Comment: @Dan, that is correct. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator.